# determing the market cap

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

I am working on a project, i am listening to the raydium v4 contract for new pairs/pools created. The issue here now is that, i am not sure how to handle determining the market cap and liquidity an a pool that was just created. Used to think dexscreener solves that but it doesn't. My code for listening to the logs is added below.

```
connection.onLogs(
    programAddress,
    async ({ logs, err, signature }) => {
      if (err) return;

      if (logs && logs.some((log) => log.includes("initialize2"))) {
        // Check if this transaction has been processed already
        if (signature !== lastProcessedTxId) {
          lastProcessedTxId = signature;
          console.log("signature: ", signature);
          await fetchRaydiumAccounts(signature, connection);
        }
      }
    },
    "finalized"
  );
```